# Setting environment variables in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, contentful, gatsby

I used this tutorial: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/docs/docs/environment-variables.md

Steps I followed:

1) install dotenv@4.0.0

2) Create two files in root folder: ".env.development" and ".env.production"

3) "follow their setup instructions" (example on dotenv npm docs)

In `gatsby-config.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const envConfig = 
dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(`.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`));
for (var k in envConfig) {
  process.env[k] = envConfig[k];
}
```

Unfortunately, when i run `gatsby develop`, `NODE_ENV` isn't set yet:

```
error Could not load gatsby-config


  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Front-End Projects\Gatsby\sebhewelt.com\.env.undefined'
```

It works when I set it manually:

```
dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(`.env.development`));
```

I need environment variables in gatsby-config because I put sensitive data in this file:

```
  {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: envConfig.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: envConfig.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN
      }
    }
```

How to make it work?

PS: Additional question - As this made me think, I know I shouldn't put passwords and tokens on github, but as netlify builds from github, is there other safe way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should only use env files when you're comfortable checking those into git. For passwords/tokens/etc. add them to Netlify or whatever build tool you use through their dashboard.

These you can access in gatsby-config.js & gatsby-node.js via `process.env.ENV_VARIABLE`.

You can't access environment variables added this way in the browser however. For this you'll need to use `.env.development` & `.env.production`.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue, I created 2 files in the root ".env.development" and ".env.production" but was still not able to access the env file variables - it was returning undefined in my gatsby-config.js file.

Got it working by npm installing dotenv and doing this:

1) When running `gatsby develop` process.env.NODE_ENV was returning undefined, but when running `gatsby build` it was returning 'production' so I define it here:

```
let env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
```

2) Then I used dotenv but specify the filepath based on the process.env.NODE_ENV

```
require('dotenv').config({path: `./.env.${env}`});
```

3) Then you can access your variables for your config:

```
module.exports = {
siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
},
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: `${process.env.CONTENTFUL_ID}`,
        accessToken: `${process.env.CONTENTFUL_TOKEN}`,
        },
    },
],
}
```

Comment: This does work. Why is it necessary, though? My takeaway from [the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) was that values defined in .env.development and .env.production would be available in gatsby-config.js.

Comment: indeed. i had the same takeaway from reading the gatsby docs as pdoherty. nonetheless, your solution rocks! the env setup works fine for me now!! Thanks

Comment: I too was getting headache due to this issue. Tried above method and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I really dislike the `.env.production` file pattern, our build system sets up and uses env variables and having extra build steps to write those into a file is weird. But Gatsby only whitelists `GATSBY_` of the env vars, with no obvious way of adding your own.

But doing that isn't so hard, you can do it by adding something like this in the `gatsby-node.js` file:

```js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, getConfig }) => {
    const config = getConfig();

    // Allow process.env.MY_WHITELIST_PREFIX_* environment variables
    const definePlugin = config.plugins.find(p => p.definitions);
    for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(process.env)) {
        if (k.startsWith("MY_WHITELIST_PREFIX_")) {
            definePlugin.definitions[`process.env.${k}`] = JSON.stringify(v);
        }
    }

    actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

After doing a few searches, I found that we can set environment variables through netlify website, here are the steps:

1. Under your own netlify console platform, please go to settings
2. Choose build & deploy tab (can be found on sidebar)
3. Choose environment sub-tab option
4. Click edit variables and add/put your credentials in
5. Done!

Comment: Not all of us are using Gatsby Cloud, however.